# Powershell data read from file contains dollar sign $

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is reading a password from a file, the password has been 'secured' using a generated AES Key.  There are three files used in the process

AES Key File Generation:

```
$KeyFile = "\\server\path\AES.key"
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 16
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | out-file $KeyFile
```

Password File Generation:

```
$PasswordFile = "\\server\path\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "\\server\path\AES.key"
$Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$Password = "Sy$tem@dmin" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile
```

Script That Grabs Password File and Converts back to Plain Text:

```
$User = "myuser"
$PasswordFile = "\\server\path\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "\\server\path\AES.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
$PlainPassword2 = $MyCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$PlainPassword2
```

The conversion back to plain text is really being done just so we can verify that the data is the same as what was initially created.

When we display the data contained in $PlainPassword2 instead of seeing **Sy$tem@dmin** as is expected, we are seeing **Sy@dmin**.

What can we do to correct this?

Comment: Change `"` to `'` in this line: `$Password = "Sy$tem@dmin" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: Mathias - wow...I can't believe I missed that.  I was so focused on the third script I never even looked at the other two.  That completely corrected my issue.  Thank you.

Comment: What also works is to escape the $ sign with a backtick. http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html    It looks like the @ terminates your uninitialized "variable" $tem that evaluates to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using double-quotes when converting the original password string:

```
$Password = "Sy$tem@dmin" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Since `"` allow for string interpolation, the parser tries to expand `$tem`, which, since it probably doesn't exist results in an empty string, thus you end up with the string you see in your output.

Use single-quotes instead:

```
$Password = 'Sy$tem@dmin' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```